# Would "..., which is what X would help me do." be correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This would be the context, roughly: "I want to (verb), which is exactly what X would help me do." Is this proper usage? It sounds somewhat awkward, but I'm not sure as to what the actual problem is. Could I replace it with something like "... which is what I believe X would help me do." or would that be equally wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Well if you fill in some values: "I want to do (build a shelf), which is exactly what (an electric screwdriver) would help me do."   Then the first "do" could actually become the problem.

Comment: I see, would your example be correct without the first "do" then?

Comment: I think so. The difference between "which is exactly what X would help me do" and "which is what I believe X would help me do" is only your level of certainty. The first sounds like you are much more certain it would help.

Comment: This is okay though: "I want to read it, which is exactly what Peter would help me do." ;  "I want to read it, which is what I believe Peter would help me do." is also okay grammatically.